# Graph Object returns null when trying to access facebook news feed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Android coding and I am trying to access facebook news feed and display in listview. I authenticated the user using facebook button widget in one activity, and passing the session to next activity. The session gets passed properly but when I try to get Response of a request for news feed and store in GraphObject, it returns null.

This is what I tried:

```
new Request(
            userSession,
            "/me/home",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    try
                    {
                        GraphObject newsFeed  = response.getGraphObject();
                        JSONObject jsonObj=newsFeed.getInnerJSONObject();
                        JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArr.length();i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonObj1=jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                            strings.add(jsonObj1.getString("id"));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
}
            }
        ).executeAsync();
}
```

When I debugged, the graph object returns null. I am new to android development and have been trying this reading the documentation. Any link to understand this better will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that:

**1.** you have correctly generated the app-id with OpenSSL and declared it in your application manifest.

**2.** application package name and app-id are correctly entered on your Facebook app details page.

**3.** you have applied for the relevant permissions and received them from FB.

**4.** the access token is valid (i.e. non-null).

**5.** the session state of the access token is OPENED.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply sir. The mistake was async tasks. I put a separate function for populating list and called inside getting the JSON object. Working now.

Comment: sir, can you look into this at your leisure. I have followed all the you mentioned for this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119346/strange-behaviour-of-graph-object-while-retrieving-facebook-news-feed

Answer (score 0):

Some times it is the problem of deprecated parameter pass in to GraphRequest so to find it write the facebook error check code into GraphRequest here I write the complete method named makeMeRequest(Accesstoken accesstoke ),Here access token is provided by the facebook so you have to pass in to it while calling this method ..Here is the code for this method

```
 private void makeMeRequest(AccessToken accesstoken) {          

             GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accesstoken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                FacebookRequestError facebookRequestError = response.getError();
                      if (facebookRequestError != null) {
                            Log.e("Error", facebookRequestError + "");
                        }
                        try {

                            System.out.println("GraphRequest response----" + object);
                            System.out.println("GraphRequest response----" + object.getString("name"));
                            System.out.println("GraphRequest response----" + object.getString("email"));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        HashMap<String, String> fb_data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        try {
                            fb_data.put("name", object.getString("name"));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            fb_data.put("name", "");
                        }
                        try {
                            fb_data.put("id", object.getString("id"));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            fb_data.put("id", "");
                        }
                        try {
                            fb_data.put("email", object.getString("email"));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            fb_data.put("email", "");
                        }

                        try {
                            fb_data.put("dob", object.getString("dob"));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            fb_data.put("dob", "");
                        }
                        pdialog.show();
                        if (fb_data.get("email").equalsIgnoreCase("") || fb_data.get("email") == null) {
                            checkSocialMedia("facebook", fb_data);
                        } else {
                            LoginProcess(fb_data, "facebook");
                        }

                    }

                });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "picture,id,name,link,email,gender,birthday,location,first_name,last_name");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }
```

In this method you can see the code this code will return the error and you will get to know about the error message and you can manage it

```
FacebookRequestError facebookRequestError = response.getError();
     if (facebookRequestError != null) {
                        Log.e("Error", facebookRequestError + "");
                    }
```

But if the error is about deprecated parameter passed into graph request object then check it as it is deprecated and if it is deprecated the it will print in to facebook error message and you have to delete it from the parameter...Here is the code of  graph request object from the method makeMeRequest()

```
 Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "picture,id,name,link,email,gender,birthday,location,first_name,last_name");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
```

You just need to remove that parameter from

```
 parameters.putString("fields", "picture,id,name,link,email,gender,birthday,location,first_name,last_name");
```

And your fb login integration work fine