# Strange behaviour of graph object while retrieving facebook news feed

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an app where I retrieve facebook news feed based on the user. I connected Nexus 4 to eclipse to run and the app ran fine. I was able to populate the values I got into a list. But when I put the apk into some other Android mobile phone, the app crashes when news feed is requested. Since it doesnt crash when I am running I am not able to zero in on the error. Any kind of error handling mechanism which can be used to avoid this ?

My Code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("limit", "100");
    new Request(
            userSession,
            "/me/home",
            params, 
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {


                    JSONArray json = null;
                    JSONObject current = null;

                    try
                    {
                        json = (JSONArray) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("data");
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // TODO: handle exception

                    }

                    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
                        try
                        {

                            current = json.getJSONObject(i);


                            String story="",name="",timeStamp="",statusMessage="",url="", id="", feedImage="";



                            try
                            {
                                feedImage=current.getString("picture").toString();
                            } catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                statusMessage=current.get("message").toString();
                            } catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }
```

And I get other values I want and populate the List. I am relatively new to android development and this is my 1st app using facebook api. Any kind of links or help will be appreciated. Thanks.

And once I added these steps instead of try-catch in getting json object from response:

```
if(response==null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(WallPosts.this, "response is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("TS","response is null");
                        populateNewsFeed("");
                    }
                    else if(response.getGraphObject()==null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(WallPosts.this, "graph object is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("TS","graph object is null");
                        populateNewsFeed("");
                    }
                    else if(response.getGraphObject().getProperty("data")==null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(WallPosts.this, "property is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("TS","Property is null");
                        populateNewsFeed("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         json = (JSONArray) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("data");
                    }
```

And the error was thrown only at graph object.

Logcat:

```
11-26 16:51:57.751: E/JavaBinder(8705): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705): Process: com.example.login, PID: 8705
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705):     at             com.example.login.WallPosts$1.onCompleted(WallPosts.java:151)
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705):     at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1658)
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705):     at     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705):     at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-26 16:52:47.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8705):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please give the logcat output of the error thrown, the line of code where the crash happens, and also mention the OS version of the device on which the app crashes.

Comment: @ZygoteInit, Thanks a lot for replying back sir. I have added the logcat output.

Comment: As for the OS version, it happens rarely in Kit kat. And happens almost every time in Lollipop, Jelly bean.